# Build spring boot app docker image by gradle: ADD failed:

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, gradle

I want to create my docker image of my app by gradle:

build.gradle

```
task buildDocker (type:Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    dockerfile = file('Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

EXPOSE 8083

ADD build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

But at the end of the execution I got this error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 28s
7 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 4 up-to-date
Docker execution failed
Command line [docker build -t com.project/app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT /home/adrian/IdeaProjects/App/build/docker] returned:
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder669437080/build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory

11:22:34 AM: Task execution finished 'buildDocker'.
```

I tried a lot of thing - rename folders, change paths etc. anything doesnt look to work.
And I dont understand why I got this error because this file: `/build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` exists.

Comment: Have you run `build` or `jar` task before? Also can you verify in console that the file exists?

Comment: Is this necessary? Because I have: `dependsOn: build`

Comment: Yes, you're right. So does the `build` task run? Is artifact built?

Comment: I got this in console: 
`> Task :check
> Task :build
> Task :buildDocker FAILED`

Comment: I dont really know so much Spring and Gradle, but I think that build is complete also because build directory is created

Comment: I see that tasks are run, hence can you verify it the file exists?

Comment: Yea, I cd into build/libs/ and file exists

Comment: Is `Dockerfile` on the same level as `build` folder?

Comment: Yea,`ls` shows me: `build  build.gradle  debScripts  Dockerfile `

Comment: No idea then, sorry. It all seems to be configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

User absolute path in destination field

```
ADD your_path/yourfile /app.jar
```